# Update tuple values on a dictionary while reading each line in a CSV file

Tags: python

Context: I'd like to update a dictionary based on the daily change on the valorization of certain stocks (taking into consideration the dates) without using list or dictionary comprehension. So, if I have a CSV file like this:

```
CSCO,2015-11-06,28.309999,28.549999,28.16,28.450001,26043900
CSCO,2015-11-05,28.5,28.610001,28.290001,28.43,21972000
CSCO,2015-11-04,28.790001,28.82,28.370001,28.469999,28552000
CSCO,2015-11-03,28.610001,28.709999,28.49,28.610001,30184300
CSCO,2015-11-02,28.870001,28.870001,28.51,28.77,28674800
NFLX,2015-11-25,124.230003,125.199997,122.360001,124.160004,10948900
NFLX,2015-11-24,123.669998,124.660004,120.029999,123.309998,18317600
NFLX,2015-11-23,124.300003,126.199997,121.660004,125.029999,15670300
NFLX,2015-11-20,120.849998,124.07,119.209999,123.839996,17887900
NFLX,2015-11-19,120.25,123.129997,119.610001,120.220001,19088800
NFLX,2015-11-18,117.940002,121,116.099998,120.629997,23287800
NFLX,2015-11-17,112.110001,118.790001,111.699997,117.099998,32936200
NFLX,2015-11-16,102.970001,111.650002,101.860001,111.349998,19802500
NFLX,2015-11-13,108.339996,109.07,103.269997,103.650002,18726600
```

...

With the structure `Company, Date, Open price, High Price, Low Price, Close Price, Volume`, I'd like to create a dictionary with this structure:

```
{'Date': ('Company', Valorization based on date)...}
```

where `valorization based on date` = Close Price/OpenPrice - 100%

I was trying to do something like this:

```
stock_dict = {}
val = 0

with open("stocks.csv", "r", encoding = "UTF-8") as stocks:
    for line in stocks:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(",") #lista de elementos
        empresa, data, abertura, high,low, fecho, volume = line

        val2 = float(fecho)/float(abertura)-1

        if data not in stock_dict:
            stock_dict[data] = (empresa, val2)
        if val2 > val:
            val = float(fecho)/float(abertura)-1
            stock_dict[data] = (empresa,val2)
```

and I get this output:

```
{'2015-11-25': ('CSCO', -0.002928257686676483),
 '2015-11-24': ('CSCO', 0.0007339449541283738),
 '2015-11-23': ('CSCO', -0.007956600361663568),
 '2015-11-20': ('CSCO', -0.0007249003262050913),
 '2015-11-19': ('CSCO', 0.009963136531365269),
 '2015-11-18': ('CSCO', 0.004444481481481466),
 '2015-11-17': ('NFLX', 0.04450982923459268),
 '2015-11-16': ('NFLX', 0.08138289714108105),
 '2015-11-13': ('CSCO', -0.0030430580812834673),
 '2015-11-12': ('CSCO', 0.0032444124008652597),
 '2015-11-11': ('CSCO', -0.009964412811387935),
 '2015-11-10': ('CSCO', -0.00709723207948898),
 '2015-11-09': ('CSCO', -0.005996472663139407),
 '2015-11-06': ('CSCO', 0.004945319849710916),
 '2015-11-05': ('CSCO', -0.002456140350877156),
 '2015-11-04': ('CSCO', -0.011115039558352136),
 '2015-11-03': ('CSCO', 0.0),
 '2015-11-02': ('HPQ', 0.1090617481956695),
 '2015-11-26': ('ARM', -0.037037014814814806)}
```

Which doesn't seem to be correct since I get negative valorizations and I'm missing company names that aren't there (I was expecting to see some AMZN stocks there as well) or the valorizations don't correspond to the company name (As an example, 'ARM' shouldn't be on the list and it should be replaced by another company 'PTI' which has a valorization of 1% for that same date). How could I update these values based on the date?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The missing companies are probably because another company has an identical date in the input row.

Comment: I'm curious why you are not using Pandas for this, which seems the more appropriate tool/library for these kind of analyses.

Comment: Right, they all have the same dates (they all start at 2015-11-02 and end at 2015-11-26), but not sure how I could to these updates based on the date

Comment: I'm still learning python and I'd like to get better at vanilla/basic python first

Comment: Is it possible that you have duplication of dates in your CSV file? Would that be a problem? Also, your sample input data doesn't match your sample output. Can you provide input and output (actual and expected)? That will help

Comment: Why couldn't `float(fecho)/float(abertura)-1` be negative? Surely there are data where `abertura` is larger than `fecho`, and the result is negative?

Comment: If there are duplicate dates, you can't use the structure you want: dictionary keys have to be unique, thus you need unique dates. Otherwise, things will overwrite each other.

Comment: @JCaesar Yes, the date range for every company starts at 2015-11-02 and ends at 2015-11-26 so the goal would be to check every date and based on the date see which company got the most daily valorization

Comment: Is this about learning Python, or learning data analyses with Python? For the latter, I'd still recommend to learn to work with Pandas.

Comment: @9769953 Learning python (currently learning dictionaries so I'd figure this could be a good exercise to learn)

Comment: the keys for your dictionary are dates so the last date you read in your csv will be the last key present in your dictionary, this is not a good format to store the data

Comment: @gold_cy Would that be also one of the reasons to why it seems that the dates don't quite correspond to the correct company / daily valorization?

Comment: yes because a dictionary can only hold one unique key. so the keys you see in the dictionary are the last dates you iterated over. a more unique key would be a tuple of (company, date).

Comment: @gold_cy is right, you cant have duplicate keys in dictionary. try researching more about dictionaries